# Installing Bash on Windows 10 (Insider Preview, Windows Subystem for Linux)

Tags: windows-10

As many of you I'm part of the fast ring of the Windows Insider Program. I recently installed the Build 14332 of Windows 10 Pro and tried to install the new Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta) feature.

I followed the tutorial and went to Settings --> Update and Securtiy --> Developers and enabled Developer mode. After that I installed the "Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)" feature and rebooted the computer. After login I opened cmd.exe and/or powershell and typed bash. I got prompted to accept the terms by typing "y" and received the following error message instead of the progressing installation:

```
Unable to download from the Windows Store. Please check your network connection.
```

As you might expect, my internet connection is up and running and I already tried the following:

- confirmed that I can download apps from the Windows Store
- disabled any security Software (in my case Bitdefender Total Security 2016, and Windows Firewall)
- executed wsreset.exe
- ran cmd.exe and powershall as administrator
- tried another network connection (mobile hotspot)
- rebooted the computer
- disabled the windows subsystem for linux, rebooted and enabled the windows subystem for linux (same result)

Additional information:

- I'm using a Wifi connection via an USB NIC (no LAN available)
- I'm using the german version of the preview (x64)

Any hints are appreciated and welcome. Maybe even from Microsoft.

Comment: I don't know how this should help. The problem of that user occurs after the installation of bash. My problem occurs before that. I cannot edit /etc/resolv.conf or other files within bash because they don't exist yet. If I miss something please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by changing my Windows account to local than to Microsoft account again.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't confirm nor deny that this is the solution, but installing the new build 14342 fixed the problem for me.